# Update a specific HashMap key value

Tags: java, object, hashmap

I am trying to update a specific HashMap key value, however, the value I am updating is being updated for all my key values. I have a HashMap of key type room (my own class) and a value of 2D int array which signifies the availability of a room.

I have a Room object which is the room (key) I want to update. The function allocate room isn't important, it just allocates a room based on a certain criteria.

row and column are just the position in the 2D array which should be updated. However, all key values at this position are being updated instead of just one specific key value.

Could anyone please shed some light on where I am going wrong?
Thanks in advance!

The way listOfRooms is generated:

```
//Rooms are added to the list as such
listOfRooms.add(new Room ("001", 72, "Lecture", "YY"));

//This function is called which adds the room and an int 2D array to a hash map
public HashMap<Room,int[][]> finaliseRooms(){ 
    int[][] roomAvailability = new int[][]{ 
        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}, 
        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}, 
        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}, 
        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}, 
        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0} }; 
     for(Room room : listOfRooms){ 
        finalListOfRooms.put(room, roomAvailability); 
     } 
     return finalListOfRooms;
}
```

Changing the value of a specific key (at this point, listOfRooms has been equated to the returned value finalListOfRooms):

```
//This is where I try to change the value of a specific key
HashMap<Room, int[][]> a = new HashMap<Room, int[][]>(listOfRooms);
Room bestRoom = allocateRoom(a, randomMLSC, row, column);

String building = bestRoom.getRoomBuilding().toString();
String roomnum = bestRoom.getRoomNumber().toString();

for(Map.Entry<Room, int[][]> entry : a.entrySet()){
   if(entry.getKey().getRoomBuilding().toString().equals(building)){
       if(entry.getKey().getRoomNumber().toString().equals(roomnum)){
            int[][] val = entry.getValue();
            if(val[row][column]==0){
               val[row][column] = 1;
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

allocateRoom:

```
public Room allocateRoom(HashMap<Room, int[][]> listOfRooms, ModuleLecturerStudentCombination mlsc, int row, int column){
        ArrayList<Room> availableRooms = new ArrayList<Room>();

        for(Map.Entry<Room, int[][]> entry : listOfRooms.entrySet()){
            int[][] av = entry.getValue();
            if(av[row][column]==0){
                availableRooms.add(entry.getKey());
            }
            //goes on to do more stuff, not with listOfRooms
        }
}
```

Comment: I think `allocateRoom` is important, especially if it is manipulating the map.

Comment: Can you add your `Room` class here for us to see? It is likely that it's hash code is not correct.

Comment: I very much suspect the problem is in how you populate the map in the first place.  Show us `allocateRoom`.

Comment: @LouisWasserman list of rooms isn't populated using allocateRoom. It is simply populated like such:

`listOfRooms.add(new Room ("001", 72, "Lecture", "YY"));`

Comment: `HashMap` doesn't *have* a constructor accepting a list. Show us how the int arrays get into the map.  Not the rooms, the int arrays.

Comment: @JoeC I have added the allocateRoom function

Comment: @LouisWasserman The way they are added is in another class where I populate everything, I add everything to listOfRooms and then I call the following function to create the hashmap with the room as the key and the 2d array as the value:

`public HashMap<Room,int[][]> finaliseRooms(){

  int[][] roomAvailability = new int[][]{

   {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
   {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
   {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
   {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
   {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}
  };

  for(Room room : listOfRooms){

   finalListOfRooms.put(room, roomAvailability);

  }

  return finalListOfRooms;
 }`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Same values for every key in hashmap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31112396/same-values-for-every-key-in-hashmap)

Comment: @michaelskellig510 First of all, please put all the extra information in the question. Second, this was the faulty code, as Louis Wasserman predicted.

Comment: Yup.  This code maps every room to the same array.  You need to make a new array for every room.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `finaliseRooms` method you assign the same array to every key, meaning that when one entry changes, all will be changed. You should move the declaration of `roomAvailability` inside the for each loop.